# NHibernate: Error dehydrating property - What the heck is this?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm doing a fairly complex NHibernate transaction in a financial system, creating a payment, recording the ledger entries, checking to see if the payment is the total amount of an invoice, if so marking the invoice as paid in full, etc... lots of fun stuff.  Naturally it has to happen inside a single transaction.

When I try to commit the change to the session, I get the following error:

```
Error dehydrating property value for C3.DataModel.CFAPTransaction.Vendor
```

Googling this did not turn up many record.  Can someone tell me what this means and where I need to focus my debugging efforts?

**UPDATE**

Per request, here is the full error message:

> ```
> NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property v  alue for C3.DataModel.CFAPTransaction.Vendor --->
> ```
>
> NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: APVendorId
>   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityMetamodel.GetPropertyIndex(String
>   propertyName) at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   entity, String propertyPath) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   obj, String propertyName, EntityMode entityMode) at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value,
>   Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute() at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session) at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event) at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() at
>   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() at
>   C3.DataModel.Repositories.NHUnitOfWork.Save() in
>   C:\projects\C3\C3.DataModel.Generated\Generated\NHibernateRepositories.generated.cs:line
>   2659 at
>   C3.WebUI.Areas.Finance.Controllers.AccountsPayableController.CreatePayment(CreatePaymentModel
>   model) in
>   C:\projects\C3\C3.WebUI\Areas\Finance\Controllers\AccountsPayableController.cs:line
>   434

**UPDATE**
Throwing NHibernate into DEBUG mode, I get a bunch of stuff like this:

> processing cascade
>   NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for:
>   C3.DataModel.APVendor
>       cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for
>   collection: C3.DataModel.APVendor.Transactions
>       done cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for
>   collection: C3.DataModel.APVendor.Transactions
>       done processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for:
>   C3.DataModel.APVendor
>       NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener         ERROR   Could not synchronize database state with session
>       NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for C3.DataModel.CFAPTransaction.Vendor --->
>   NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: APVendorId
>   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityMetamodel.GetPropertyIndex(String
>   propertyName) at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   entity, String propertyPath) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   obj, String propertyName, EntityMode entityMode) at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value,
>   Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute() at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session)
>       C3.WebUI.Areas.Finance.Controllers.AccountsPayableController       ERROR   C3.WebUI.Areas.Finance.Controllers.AccountsPayableController:
>   No additional information.
>       NHibernate.PropertyValueException: Error dehydrating property value for C3.DataModel.CFAPTransaction.Vendor --->
>   NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: APVendorId
>   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.EntityMetamodel.GetPropertyIndex(String
>   propertyName) at
>   NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   entity, String propertyPath) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GetPropertyValue(Object
>   obj, String propertyName, EntityMode entityMode) at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.NullSafeSet(IDbCommand st, Object value,
>   Int32 index, Boolean[] settable, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Dehydrate(Object
>   id, Object[] fields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty,
>   Boolean[][] includeColumns, Int32 table, IDbCommand statement,
>   ISessionImplementor session, Int32 index) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Boolean[] notNull, Int32 j, SqlCommandInfo sql,
>   Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object id,
>   Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) at
>   NHibernate.Action.EntityInsertAction.Execute() at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions() at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource
>   session) at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event) at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush() at
>   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit() at
>   C3.DataModel.Repositories.NHUnitOfWork.Save() in
>   C:\projects\C3\C3.DataModel.Generated\Generated\NHibernateRepositories.generated.cs:line
>   2659 at
>   C3.WebUI.Areas.Finance.Controllers.AccountsPayableController.CreatePayment(CreatePaymentModel
>   model) in
>   C:\projects\C3\C3.WebUI\Areas\Finance\Controllers\AccountsPayableController.cs:line
>   434

It does not appear this is occurring when querying the database.  I have a feeling it has problems with me creating a bunch of objects, relating them, and then trying to persist them, but that's a pure guess.

Comment: What's the full exception, and is there an inner exception?

Comment: what about **Unable to resolve property: APVendorId** - does that give you a clue? Is the mapping wrong? The `NHUnitOfWork.Save()` is trying to write out to a column and is looking for a Property called APVendorId.

Comment: It doesn't *seem* to be wrong.  The individual repositories seem to perform and build properly.  The generated schema seems correct.

Comment: Try putting a profiler on the SQL and also increasing the logging in NHibernate. I find that most issues with NHiberate are resolved using clues from it's amazing logging (log4net). See what SQL gets generated and what NHiberate is expecting..

Comment: If that is the case I would reduce the size of the graph in the save until it works and work backwards. If that failed - I may even get the nhibernate source out. But at this point if all you are doing is creating a graph of objects then it might be time to simplify graph and try a little at a time.

Comment: What version of NHibernate is this? There are various issues in NH 2.0 with the Linq provider and various mapping types (ie component).

Comment: This is 3.2, non-fluent.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's likely that nhibernate is not showing the correct property of error, check the adjacent properties in the mapping file, looking for errors in relationship between data types from your database and data types from .net or repeated columns in properties... also check this link [Fluent NHibernate - IndexOutOfRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689054/fluent-nhibernate-indexoutofrange)

Comment: This is apparently what happened.  I had a typo in a different property and I guess it affected this one.  I wouldn't have an issue with this except that the message was so freaking cryptic.

Comment: It's not cryptic - just look at the inner exception in the info you pasted.

Comment: Um... no, looking at this going on 6 years later, it's still cryptic and a horrible error message.

Answer (score 3):

You should check CFAPTransaction mapping, It looks like you wanted to specify one Vendor for each transaction. In this case your mapping has to be like below code.

```
public CFAPTransactionMap()
{
  HasOne(x => x.Vendor).ForeignKey("VendorId").Cascade.All();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was a missing Identity Specification on the SQL-Server.

Simple object:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public class EmployeeMap : ClassMapping<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID, map => { map.Generator(Generators.Identity); map.UnsavedValue(0); });
    }
}
```

SQL:

Here is the ID column with the primary key constraint.

[image: ID column with constraint]

And here you can see the missing Identity Specification, which is causing the problem.
[image: Missing Identity Specification]

To solve the problem, you have to specify the ID column as `IDENTITY`
i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(0, 1)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. This is my sample mappings:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.objPerson, map => { map.Column("PersonID"); map.NotNullable(false); });
Property(x => x.intPersonID, map => map.Column("PersonID"));
```

If I tried to persist/save this on my database by populating only the property `intPersonID` and making the `objPerson` null, this will trigger the dehydrating error on all your properties!

The reason I am just populating `intPersonID` is to prevent querying on the database to get the `objPerson` before saving to the database. Unfortunately, it will trigger an error, so I modified my mappings and corrected with this:

```
ManyToOne(x => x.objPerson, map => { map.Column("PersonID"); map.NotNullable(false); });
```

Or if I want to prevent querying on the database by getting the whole object, I will just use this mapping instead:

```
Property(x => x.intPersonID, map => map.Column("PersonID"));
```

But combining them is not possible.

Comment: In my case I needed to persists the parent entity without the child, so adding the ReadOnly flag of the many-to-one part of the relation worked as in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33253799/97471

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the exception was accurately identifying the property that was the cause of the error. I had a many-to-one property that was lacking a `cascade` definition. `"save-update"` prevents the error:

```
<many-to-one name="FocusType" cascade="save-update"
    class="MyInfrastructure.FocusType, MyInfrastructure">
    <column name="FocusTypeId" sql-type="int" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
```

Answer (score -1):

a smart person once told me to add this to my mapping

```
.Length(int.MaxValue);
```